# Cut string if the string size exceeds 5000 bytes

Tags: python, pandas, string, byte

Currently I am trying to translate a Pandas dataframe with Amazon Translate however, the max length of request text allowed is 5000 bytes and the dataframe contains multiple strings that exceed this limit.

Therefore I want to implement a solution that is able to cut the string of the "Content" column in chunks below 5000 bytes, amount of chunks dependent on the original string size, so that the limit is not exceeded and there is no lost of text.

To be more precise: the dataframe contains 3 columns:

```
 Newspaper  Date                                            Content
6      Trouw  2018  Het is de laatste kolenmijn in Duitsland de Pr...
7      Trouw  2018  Liever wat meer kwijt aan energieheffing dan r...
8      Trouw  2018  De VVD doet een voorstel dat op het Binnenhof ...
9      Trouw  2018  In Nederland bestaat grote weerstand tegen ker...
10     Trouw  2017  Theo Potma 1932  2017 had zijn blocnote altijd...
11     Trouw  2017  Hoe en hoe snel kan Nederland zijn beloften op...
12     Trouw  2017  transitie  Hoe en hoe snel kan Nederland zijn ...
14     Trouw  2016  Welke ideeën koestert Angela Merkel Henri Beun...
15     Trouw  2016  Welke ideeën koestert Angela Merkel Henri Beun...
16     Trouw  2015  Rapport Dwing burger CO\n    Nederland heeft e...
```

And only the "Content" column should be checked for string size and cut in chunks but keep the original "Newspaper" and "Date" column data. By doing so I can still trace back the text to the original row.

Is there anyone who can help with such a solution?

Comment: What text encoding you want to use?

Comment: Good one: utf-8

Comment: is the service used via an API or do you insert it into a database? pandas has a `DataFrame.memory_usage()` but it computes for entire columns  not for rows. Won't context get lost if you cut the column

Comment: That is a valid point. I have decided to delete the rows in which the column content contains more than 5000 bytes. Thanks for your advice!